# Completely antiviral resistant, possible?

Tags: medicine, viruses

My Viral TB virus I made is completely antiviral resistant. It can and will infect every single part of the humanoid's body. Here is just a minority of what it causes:

- Pancarditis(whole heart inflamed)
- Anemia(Hemolytic and IDA(Iron Deficency Anemia) both)
- Double Pneumonia(Pneumonia in both lungs)

Per organ system there is a lot more going on but I am not sure I should put every single symptom here.

And here is where the TB in its name comes from. The virus after some time in a particular organ system forms granulomas and becomes latent there. But some viruses spread before they become part of the granulomas and infect more parts of the body. Most of the viruses have died from phagocytosis but these viruses are trapped in the granulomas to protect the body.

Once the virus has infected every single part of the body(blood, reproductive system, you name it) it eventually becomes latent throughout the body and the humanoid starts to heal. But later on it starts again in the same place that it started first(so if it started in the lungs, it starts again in the lungs, if it started in the GI tract, it starts again in the GI tract.

And the cycle repeats but this time the immunity is stronger so more viruses are killed. It usually takes 5-6 reinfections(latent becoming active again) before all the viruses are killed by the immune system.

And while this is happening a lot of things are needed for treatment. 1 of those things is a nutrient IV when the patient has digestive issues that are just too strong for eating food normally(malabsorption, nausea and vomiting, diarrhea, etc.)

But yeah this virus is resistant to every antiviral, natural and synthetic so antivirals are useless.

**Is it possible for a virus to be antiviral resistant and if so are antivirals useless or can they be used to treat the symptoms?**

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you define as an antiviral.  The extremes are pretty darn effective.  A flamethrower is remarkably effective at curing cancer, though the side effects suggest to me that it wont be approved by the FDA any time soon.

The real trick is that there's a war going on.  For example, HIV was virtually immune to every antiviral out there... until we started actually trying to target it.  We tore it apart, started to figure out what makes it tick, and now we have antivirals custom designed to handle HIV.  But, for a while, it was immune to everything.

Let the games begin.  How fast can humans find new antivirals specifically targeted towards your particular virus?  In theory it's just an information game, so either side *could* win.  However, I'd like to point out that, to cause all of those terrible symptoms all over, your virus is going to have to be very active.  The likelyhood of such an active virus having no weak spots to target strikes me as very low.

The first place I'd look for antivirals, myself, would be in the bodies of those survivors.  They, by definition, have found an antiviral that works.  Whether it is replicatable in the body of others may be a different story.

Comment: Drug resistant strains do still develop in HIV though right?

Comment: @Feyre Correct, hence the war.  They develop resistances, and then we find new ways to overcome them.  And as you pointed out, some of the approaches we have are exotic -- all the way up to *not* using drugs in order to get the virus to overcommit to the non-resistant varieties!  You have to admit, it's almost crazy when you think about it.

Comment: But antibodies are not just antivirals. And it is antibodies that save them from death as well as the fact that it goes between active and latent for every organ system and every cycle. And what do you mean no weak spots? Of course there are going to be weak spots, Red Blood Cells for one since they have no nucleus and the red blood cells have to burst in order for an infection of the red blood cells to be detected since they can't produce any MHCI that would usually signal that the cell is infected. And of course babies and immunocompromised are going to be weak spots on the macro scale.

Comment: I mean weak spots in the virus.  It's genetic code is the thing we're really trying to stop.  If it were quiet and selective, it may be reasonable to suggest that it is hard to find any chinks in its armor.  However, if it's out there being as deadly as possible, it's going to need to be active.  Active things are easier to spot, and attack.

Comment: But if it can infect every organ system in the body, it has to be tough and if it is tough against the immune system(able to infect white blood cells and the immune system needing to form granulomas), I wouldn't be surprised if it is tough against all antivirals. It may be easy to spot due to the severe symptoms but it is harder to attack than your normal virus both biologically with the immune system and pharmacologically and so far, extreme supportive care(nutrient IV, Iron supplements, etc.) is the maximum that they can do and they have to leave the immune system fighting the virus itself.

Comment: @Caters Now we're getting into the tricky part.  The number of possible viruses is unimaginably huge.  Whether toughness against the immune system means toughness against targeted synthetic antivirals is not obvious.  Maybe they will be, or maybe they wont.  It depends *strongly* on how the virus protects itself from the immune system.  That being said, you're up against a multi-billion dollar industry if you're a virus like that.  The amount of raw creativity we can put up against it is staggering.  We have tools to use against malignant cancers, which body can't do anything about.

Answer (score 1):

Viruses "reproduce" rapidly, and while they aren't lifeforms, they do mutate. Viruses that are more prone to mutation have a higher likelihood of developing a mutation that makes individual virions resistant to drugs.
These virions are then able to proliferate freely.

It is often the case that this mutation makes the virion less able to compete with non-resistant strains, and hence they only become prolific when the host body takes anti-viral drugs.

Even when medication protocols are followed carefully, drug resistance happens in HIV.

A person with HIV can go through waves of medication prescription, where different HIV strains become more or less prevalent depending on the drugs (if any) that are used. When the drugs are stopped, the drug-resistant strains are outcompeted by the non-resistant ones.

When non-resistant strains become more prevalent, the medications are once again administered.

This regime can keep a virus relatively in check, but can't eliminate it.